# Different RegEx from Chrome to Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this regex:

```
var RE_SSN = /^[A-Åa-å0-9,\!\-\?\""\. ]{3,999}$/;
```

Which I use in a JS-function

```
function checkSsn(ssn){

 if (RE_SSN.test(ssn)) {    
  javascript:addAppointment(document.forms[0])
  alert("YES");
 } else {
    alert("NO");
 }
}
```

When I type `12345Test` in Chrome the regex passes, and thats the point. But in IE the String cannot start with numbers. Seems to me that IE is just made for making my life miserable.. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: I cannot say why IE don't allow numbers at the beginning, but just one comment: [A-Åa-å] is exactly the same as [A-å], since [A-Å] matches from A (0x41) to Å (0xC5), and [a-å] matches from A (0x61) to å (0xE5). You probably mean [A-Za-zÆØÅæøå0-9,\!\-\?\"\. ], because otherwise, you'd miss the lower-case letters æ and ø. (I'm assuming you are Norwegian).

Comment: Also, why are there double double-quotes?

Comment: The double double quotes, frankly I don't know. Anyway thanks for the comment :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is the construction `A-Åa-å` which is being interpreted differently. IE doesn't think `T` is in that range.

This may be something to do with the character set detection. Is the script encoded in UTF-8? Does it start with the UTF-8 BOM? If not then adding one will probably help - at least by making the browsers behave the same.

Secondly, I am not sure what your intent is by writing `A-Åa-å`, but it seems an unusual thing to put into a regex.

I suggest you change the regex to break out the characters into more natural ranges, e.g. to `A-Za-zÅå`, or expanding the ranges altogether.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to allow digits and letters from (I suppose) [norwegian alphabet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norwegian_alphabet) try this regexp using unicode sequences

```
var RE_SSN = /^[a-zA-Z\u00C5\u00C6\u00D8\u00E5\u00E6\u00F8\!\-\?\""\. ]{3,999}$/;
```

where

```
\u00C5 > Å  
\u00C6 > Æ   
\u00D8 > Ø  
\u00E5 > å  
\u00E6 > æ  
\u00F8 > ø
```

Hope this helps